# Ink Email template generate a custom email from template

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, zurb-ink

I'm trying to make an email form template. So that it outputs one of the ink responsive designs to use in an email.

I would love some guidance on this. Basically in my mind at the moment, The user would enter text in for the main body. Then afterwards the user would click submit and the html page would be generated. Which is the issue. I have no idea how i would go about doing this.

What would be the best way to do this? Html? javascript? Rails?

Any help would be great.

Comment: You can use ckeditor plugin for this . you can use ckeditor gem to implement ckeditor in rails app.

Comment: I need it simpler than that, Simple text boxes etc